# Installation Error alongside windows

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I tried to install Ubuntu on my Windows 7 64-bit desktop alongside windows.

1. Initially I run the set up file and completed my basic installation
2. I restarted my machine. Ubuntu OS loaded
3. When it was getting loaded, it pops up an error message `No root file system    defined`, then the machine was hanged up
4. I restarted my machine and tried running Ubuntu in safe mode, this time I viewed    the Ubuntu desktop screen
5. I clicked Install Ubuntu file, I proceeded and stuck again in the disk partition.

Finally, I couldn't able to install. Please help me out

Comment: During partition assign the filesystem to be mounted on your root (`/`) directory. i.e set the "mount" field of your desired partition where you want the install the root directory to `/`.

Comment: Actually, I rebooted the system to complete the ubuntu installation .ERROR1: Failed to partition the selected disk (as superuser). This probably happened because there are too many (primary) partitions in the partition table.

Comment: ERROR 2: I clicked Ok on that pop-up. Another Error throws up, " No root file system (as superuser). No root file system is defined. Please correct this from the partitioning menu